# How to pass collection of generic expressions into method if types are different?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, expression, func

I need to generate string key based on Api Controller, Action and input params.
For this I have method like:

```
public string MakeCacheKey<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> action) where T : ApiController
    {
        string controllerName = typeof(T).Name; 

        if (action.Body is MethodCallExpression methodCall)
        {
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            ParameterInfo[] parameterInfos = methodCall.Method.GetParameters();

            for (var i = 0; i < methodCall.Arguments.Count; i++)
            {
                object value = GetExpressionValue(methodCall.Arguments[i]);
                parameters.Add(parameterInfos[i].Name, value);
            }

            string actionName = methodCall.Method.Name;
            return this.MakeCacheKeyInternal(controllerName, actionName, parameters);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

It works fine, but now I would like to call this method for multiple expressions where `T` is different  (different controller) like:

```
var cacheKeys = actions.Select(action => this._cacheKeyGenerator.MakeCacheKey(action, true)).ToList();
```

where `IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> actions`

so I would like to have actions like :

```
new List<Expression<Func<ApiController, object>>> {c => ((HomeApiController)c).Get(1), c => ((TeamApiController)c).GetAll()}
```

When I have actions like above, in `MakeCacheKey` method controllerName will be `ApiController` which isn't what I need. For 1st case I need name `HomeApiController` and for 2nd - `TeamApiController`.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: I can't think of a clever way to do it but what about passing the name as an additional parameter? :)

Comment: @SelmanGenç, well, yes, it is one solution... I thought I can somehow take type from Func... but don't know how

Comment: So you want to make single cache key from multiple actions?

Comment: @Evk, no. A collection of different... but I would like to pass different expressions in `actions` parameter

Comment: what you are asking is that there is an object which is type of some base class but the underlying object is actually an inherited type. and you want to find out the inherited type from the base object, right?

Comment: @SelmanGenç, generally yes.